# Troubles with substring, trim, trimend

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I'm trying to take an array of email addresses (in the form of username@company.com) which is generated from:

```
$users = get-MSOLUser -All | where {$_.isLicensed -eq "TRUE" -and $_.Licenses.AccountSKUID -eq "my_license"} | select userprincipalname
```

And get just the username from each.  I start with `username@company.com` and want to end up with `username`.  I have tried various ways using substring, Trim, TrimEnd, etc and can't get any of them working.

```
$username = $users | %{$_.substring(0,$users.length - 12)}
$users | %{$_.trimend("@company.com")}
$users | %{$_.trimend(12)}
```

All of the above give errors including the two below.

Method invocation failed because `[Selected.Microsoft.Online.Administration.User]` does not 
contain a method named `substring`.

Method invocation failed because `[Selected.Microsoft.Online.Administration.User]` does not 
contain a method named `trimend`.

What am I doing wrong with the syntax, or is there something else, like a module I haven't imported, or how my syntax is trying to work with an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will return you a list of all usernames (without domain) that fulfills your conditions:

```
$users = Get-MSOLUser -All | 
    Where-Object {$_.isLicensed -eq "TRUE" -and $_.Licenses.AccountSKUID -eq "my_license"} | 
    ForEach-Object { $_.userprincipalname -replace '@.*' }
```

Comment: I like that piece of code.  Tested and works perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need to work with the property, not with the object, so you would probably want to do something like:

```
select -expandproperty userprincipalname
```

but that would create an array of userprincipalnames, so no other attributes.

When you run `get-MSOLUser` you get back an object, with a bunch of properties. When you do `select -expandproperty` you are getting back only certain property, but not an object itself. You are getting back a `system.string` object. And that object has all those methods you are trying to invoke.

Comment: adding -expandproperty to my statement totally worked.  I guess I should read up on how that works.  Thank you very much.

Comment: well, let me elaborate in my answer a bit

Comment: Starting off with BSmith@company.com.  Any idea why $users | %{$_.trimend("@company.com")} returns (sometimes) BSmit, but $users | %{$_.trimend("ompany.com")} returns BSmith@c?  Having @ or not makes a big difference in results.

Comment: what do you mean sometimes? O_o anyway, the quirk with `trim` is that it deletes all the characters. Say `'aaaa'.Trimend('a')`, will delete everything, but `'aaaba'.Trimend('ba')` will also delete everything, so it deletes all the occurrences of the characters in the `Trim` method.

Comment: In the array of strings (username@company.com) when I TrimEnd ("@company.com") for some of the strings, it cuts off the last 1 to couple characters (BSmi).  If I test that list with TrimEnd("company.com") or less ("ompany.com") the result is BSmith@ or BSmith@c.  Does that make sense?

Comment: It can do that, it will `trim` all the characters (that are passed to the `trim` method) it can get to. So your company name should have both `t` and `h` in it. to understand that test `trim` with various strings: like `'aa'.Trim('a')`,`'ababa'.Trim('a')`, `'abacacba'.Trim('ab')` and so on